# rangeOfUnit returns `NSNotFound` for weeks in month (iOS7 bug)

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, calendar

Hello I have problem with `rangeOfUnit()` method from `NSCalendar`. I get `NSNotFound` value while I am expecting values in range <4,6> (number of weeks in one month). What's really worry me it's the platform dependent (doesn't work on iOS7). The bug has been found while I was investigating [CVCalendar](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) component. I have set English language and Gregorian Calendar on my iPhone 4S with iOS 7.1.1.

```
// Range of the month.
let range = calendar.rangeOfUnit(NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfMonth, inUnit: NSCalendarUnit.Month, forDate: date)
// Should return values in range <4,6>
print("Range \(range)")
let range2 = calendar.rangeOfUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Month, inUnit: NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfMonth, forDate: date)
// Invalid range. No week contains no months.
print("Range \(range2)")
let range3 = calendar.rangeOfUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Weekday, inUnit: NSCalendarUnit.Month, forDate: date)
print("Range \(range3)")
```

Printed date on console:

```
po date
2015-11-17 10:05:39 +0000
```

Console output on iOS9 simulator and other not-iOS7 devices:

```
Range (1,5)
Range (2147483647,2147483647)
Range (1,7)
```

Console output on iOS7 device:

```
Range (2147483647,2147483647)
Range (2147483647,2147483647)
Range (1,7)
```

Comment: What is UICalendar? Do you mean NSCalendar? – And what is the difference between first and last range?

Comment: I'm sorry I mean `NSCalendar` from Foundation framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the availability checks in Swift 2.

```
let weekOfMonthUnit: NSCalendarUnit
if #available(iOS 8, *) {
    weekOfMonthUnit = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfMonth
} else {
    weekOfMonthUnit = NSCalendarUnit.NSWeekCalendarUnit
}
let range = calendar.rangeOfUnit(weekOfMonthUnit, inUnit: NSCalendarUnit.Month, forDate: date)
print("Range \(range)")
```